# Xamarin.Android - How to continue a process while app is minimized or screen is locked

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've created a Xamarin app that checks the users current location every couple minutes.  My problem is it doesn't work when I minimize the app or the screen locks.  Is there a way for me to continue the process while minimized or when the phone is locked?

This function checks to see if the user is at the destination location.

```
    public bool atLocation(decimal currentLat, decimal currentLong, decimal destLat, decimal destLong)
    {
        decimal GPSLatitudePadding = 0.001M;
        decimal GPSLongitudePadding = 0.001M;
        var totalLowerLatitude = Convert.ToDecimal((destLat - GPSLatitudePadding).ToString("#.####"));
        var totalLowerLongitude = Convert.ToDecimal((destLong + GPSLongitudePadding).ToString("#.####"));
        var totalUpperLatitude = Convert.ToDecimal((destLat + GPSLatitudePadding).ToString("#.####"));
        var totalUpperLongitude = Convert.ToDecimal((destLong - GPSLongitudePadding).ToString("#.####"));

        if ((Convert.ToDecimal(destLat) >= totalLowerLatitude) && 
        (Convert.ToDecimal(destLat) <= totalUpperLatitude) && 
        (Convert.ToDecimal(destLong) <= totalLowerLongitude) && 
        (Convert.ToDecimal(destLong) >= totalUpperLongitude))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

If the user is at the destination for 2 instances of 2 minutes the process is ended.  This is where you could start a new process or update a database.

```
    int intNumberOfTimesFoundAtLocation = 0;
    void OnLocationResult(object sender, Android.Locations.Location location)
    {
        decimal currentLatitude =  Convert.ToDecimal(location.Latitude); 
        decimal currentLongitude = Convert.ToDecimal(location.Longitude); 
        decimal destLatitude = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dblDestLatitude); 
        decimal destLongitude = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dblDestLongitude); 
        var atLocation = locationQ.atLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, destLatitude, destLongitude);

        if (ayLocation == true)
        {
            intNumberOfTimesFoundAtLocation = intNumberOfTimesFoundAtLocation + 1;
            if(intNumberOfTimesFoundAtLocation == 2)
            { 
                client.RemoveLocationUpdates(locationCallback);

            }
        }
    }
```

I call this function to start the process

```
    MyLocationCallback locationCallback;
    FusedLocationProviderClient client;

    public async void StartLocationUpdatesAsync()
    {
        // Create a callback that will get the location updates
        if (locationCallback == null)
        {
            locationCallback = new MyLocationCallback();
            locationCallback.LocationUpdated += OnLocationResult;
        }

        // Get the current client
        if (client == null)
            client = LocationServices.GetFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try
        {
            locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                                      .SetInterval(120000)
                                      .SetFastestInterval(120000)                                          
                           .SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy);

            await client.RequestLocationUpdatesAsync(locationRequest, locationCallback);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle exception here if failed to register
        }
    }

}

class MyLocationCallback : LocationCallback
{
    public EventHandler<Android.Locations.Location> LocationUpdated;
    public override void OnLocationResult(LocationResult result)
    {
        base.OnLocationResult(result);
        LocationUpdated?.Invoke(this, result.LastLocation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a foreground service.
- Inside service call the following code to start the request updates.

  ```
  locationLogger = new LocationLogger();
  locationLogger.LogInterval = _currentInterval;
  locationLogger.StopUpdates();
  locationLogger.StartRequestionUpdates();
  ```

Check [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kTfPCIswrM1LLr8k2df_e2iwb8b5ESWa/view?usp=sharing) for the code

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi G., I'm not sure how this fits into my code. Can you explain a little more?  The link doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: The link is a google drive link for some code that i did myself and fits your requirement exactly if you want me to elaborate more it will take time so you will have to wait